# Testing nested index controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller, nested

My routes file looks like this:

```
resources :people do
  resources :text_messages, only: [:index, :new, :create]
end
```

And my `/app/controllers/text_messages_controllers.rb` looks like:

```
class TextMessagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    puts 'You have reached the index controller'
    @messages = Message.all
  end
end
```

Here's the `/spec/controllers/text_messages_controller_spec.rb`

```
describe TextMessagesController do
  describe 'GET #index' do
    it 'shows all the messages to that user' do
      person = create(:person)
      message = create(:message, person: person)

      get :index, person_id: person.id

      expect(assigns(:messages)).to include(message)
    end
  end
end
```

When I run the test however, it fails saying `@messages` is nil and does not print out the text. Why is this test not reaching the controller action? It works great in development when I visit the url.

Comment: you have `puts "you've reached this controller action"` instead of `@messages TextMessage.all` or something. Assign a `@messages` variable in index method and it should work.

Comment: Apologies, I actually did have something like that and it gave me the same error. I updated my question to be clearer.